# show a dynamic select input from mysql table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have used a select box to identify the users age group. Accroding to the value of the age group, I need to display diffrent options

For eg.

```
<select name="age_group">
    <option value="1">15-25</option>
    <option value="2">26-35</option>
    <option value="3">35-60</option>
    <option value="4">60 or above</option>
</select>
```

If the user selects the first option I need to display contents of 'tbl_hobbies' (mysql table) with age group 1 in another select box.

```
<select name="hobbies" id="hobbies">
    <option>watching movies</option>
    <option>playing computer games</option>
    <option>chatting</option>
</select>
```

For the second option (26-35), I need to display 'tbl_hobbies' contents with age group 2

```
<select name="hobbies" id="hobbies">
    <option>Cleaning Home</option>
    <option>Reading</option>
    <option>Travelling</option>
</select>
```

How can I achieve this using AJAX or is this possible without using AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add an id to age group

```
<select name="age_group" id="age_group">
```

Then

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#age_group').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: { group_id: $(this).val() },
            dataType: "html"
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
            $('#hobbies').html(msg);
        });
    });
});
```

In ajax.php you get all hobbies where group_id = $_POST['group_id']

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM tbl_hobbies WHERE group_id = ".$_POST['group_id'];
// Execute your query and put the result in a variable (example $result_query)
// Then loop it
foreach($result_query as $row) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}
```

**NB :** The loop may change according to your method to retrieve data

Comment: your answer is really helpful for beginners like me. I found a helpful article to create dynamic select boxes.  http://www.htmlexplorer.com/2014/02/create-dynamic-select-list-from-mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put all option together and hide option as per user choice

```
<select name="hobbies" id="hobbies">
<option class="group_1">Cleaning Home</option>
<option class="group_1">Reading</option>
<option class="group_1">Travelling</option>
<option class="group_2">watching movies</option>
<option class="group_2">playing computer games</option>
<option class="group_2">chatting</option>
```

Comment: Use Jquery to hide options

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
<select id="age_select" name="age_group">
    <option value="1">15-25</option>
    <option value="2">26-35</option>
    <option value="3">35-60</option>
    <option value="4">60 or above</option>
</select>
<select name="hobbies1" id="hobbies1">
    <option>watching movies</option>
    <option>playing computer games</option>
    <option>chatting</option>
</select> 

<select name="hobbies2" id="hobbies2">
    <option>Cleaning Home</option>
    <option>Reading</option>
    <option>Travelling</option>
</select>
```

and your jquery script look like this

```
<script>
$('#age_select').on('change'.function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  if ( value == '1' ) {
      $('#hobbies1').show();
      $('#hobbies2').hide();
  } else if ( value == '2' ) {
      $('#hobbies2').show();
      $('#hobbies1').hide();
  }
});
</script>
```

and if you want to pass through ajax

```
$('#age_select').on('change'.function(){
     var value = $(this).val();
     var data = 'age='+value;
     $.post(
         'abc.php',
         data
     ).success(function(resp){

     });
});
```

Comment: I need to delete the previous content from the DOM while I select a new option. Will this hide() remove the content from DOM?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called "**Dynamic dependent dropdowns**". You can view a very good demo [***`here`***](http://www.snilesh.com/demo/dynamic_selectbox/).

**Algorithm**

```
1. Get all the options from database              // do that using php
2. Assign classes to them according to group      // do that using php
3. Put all of them in HTML                        // do that using php
4. Show/hide on event                             // do that using jQuery/javascript
```

**Example**

```
    <select id="age_select" name="age_group">
        <option value="1">15-25</option>
        <option value="2">26-35</option>
        <option value="3">35-60</option>
        <option value="4">60 or above</option>
    </select>
    <select name="hobbies1" id="hobbies1">
        <option value="wm" class="grp age-grp-1">watching movies</option>
        <option value="pcg" class="grp age-grp-1>playing computer games</option>
        <option value="chat" class="grp age-grp-2>chatting</option>
        <option value="ch" class="grp age-grp-2>Cleaning Home</option>
        <option value="rea" class="grp age-grp-3>Reading</option>
        <option value="tr" class="grp age-grp-4>Travelling</option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    // script to execute when you change option from first dropdown
    $('#age_select').on('change'.function(){
        var ageGrp = $(this).val();

        // first, hide all options
        $('.grp').hide();

        // show options only for selected group
        $('.age-grp-'+ageGrp).show();
    });
    </script>
```

Hope this helps!!!